# Apache Server RewriteRule to Tomcat WAR

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, mod-rewrite, war

I'm trying to get Apache's RewriteEngine to rewrite some URL's to Tomcat Webapp Directories.
It already works partially, but there is one thing that I cannot achieve.

This is the scenario:

I have apache and a tomcat running on a vps.
On the tomcat I have a webapp called XYZ.
On Apache, I use the jk_mod module with workers.properties to "connect" to the tomcat.
In my httpd.conf I have a VitualHost set up as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName abc.domain.com
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /XYZ/$1 [L,PT]
   JkMount /* XYZ
</VirtualHost>
```

So far, so good. Without the RewriteRule I'd have to open the URL like this:

```
abc.domain.com/XYZ/home (where "home" is the jsp)
abc.domain.com/XYZ/customers
etc...
```

And the WITH the RewriteRule I'm down to this:

```
abc.domain.com/home
abc.domain.com/customers
etc...
```

Which is already pretty good for my goal, but there is just one more thing that needs to be done: I want to be able to open `abc.domain.com` and to be redirected to the last example above (home jsp).

I've tried adding some other RewriteRules that would rewrite the root to `/XYZ/home` and also tried a `Redirect`, but none of those worked as I expected them to (nothing happened)...

Can somebody please explain, how I can achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Put the Redirect above the RewriteEngine clause.

Something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName abc.domain.com
   Redirect 301 ^/$ /home
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /XYZ/$1 [L,PT]
   JkMount /* XYZ
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Rijndael! 
Unfortunately, this didn't work very well...
With this approach I get a redirect loop and the URL looks somewhat like this: http://abc.domain.com/homeXYZ/homeXYZ/homeXYZ/homeXYZ/.....

I'll investigate further, maybe I'll find the reason myself.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a RewriteRule that does what I need.

Comment: my bad, it should have been Redirect 301 ^/$ /home

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work in the end. Using a second RewriteRule. I guess that I had some mistakes in my wildcard / regex in my previous tries.

This is what works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName abc.domain.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /XYZ/$1 [L,PT]
  RewriteRule ^/$ /XYZ/home [L,PT]   # <---- This 
  JkMount /* XYZ
</VirtualHost>
```

During my research I also learnt that a `Redirect 301 / /home` will basically redirect everything, NOT only the root, as would have needed it to.